# How i can insert a Google Service Account as a device in registry of Google Cloud IoT

Tags: service-accounts, google-cloud-iot

What i'm asking is if is possible (or nonsense) adding a service account as a Google Cloud IoT registry as a device. Actually i'm using a google library and the service account authentication flow to use the library eg. @google-coud/pubsub to push message to a pubsub topic defined into Google IoT Core registry ... but i cannot handle the app where the library is used as a device of the registry too! I've tried to create a device into Google Cloud IoT core with the public key of the service account but i cannot see heartbeat and telemetry event received ... of course because the service account is not seen as IoT device ...

Comment: Not able to understand your question completely. Why do we need to store service account as device. Cant you use service account to generate public and private keys and then bind device to public and private key that you generted through service-account

Comment: Yep that's what i'm doing.... but i cannot handle the keys through Google Cloud IoT, that's my question if i can handle the keys of services account in the device section of Google Cloud IoT > Device